# creating multiply nested lists in r

Tags: r, list, multidimensional-array

I would like to create a structure of lists in order to map a multidimensional data frame.
The list will contain a different number of indices in each combination of dimensions, corresponding to the observations fulfilling a certain condition.

For example, the entry ListOfLists[1,1,2,6,9] (the syntax is not correct, it's just a symbolic way of describing the desired output) would contain the intersection of observations from the first interval of dimension 1, the first interval of dimension 2, the 2nd interval of dimension 3, the 6th interval of dimension 4 and the 9th interval of dimension 5.

For example, lets say that observations 8, 10, and 20 satisfy such a condition.
I would naively think to write this as follows:

```
L = list()
L[[1]][[1]][[2]][[6]][[9]] = c(8, 10, 20)
```

But this of course doesn't work.

Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: No, because I don't know how to create it. The idea is that if I try to access the element [[1]][[1]][[2]][[3]][[9]], I will find c(8, 10, 12) as the answer

Comment: what about using a integer vector to describe the index? `L <- list();
L[[1]] <- list(index=c(1,1,2,6,9), value=c(8, 10, 20))` I know that is not the same but it can be used to construct the desired nested list.

Comment: good idea. Thanks!

Comment: "For example, the entry ListOfLists[1,1,2,6,9] (the syntax is not correct". It could be correct, if you used an array instead of a list of lists. e.g. `a <- array(list(), dim = rep(10, 5)); 

a[1,1,2,6,9] <- list(c(8, 10, 20))`. I think jogo's idea is probably better though.